# Mocking USB input

Tags: testing, mocking, usb

Our product includes some custom hardware, that connects to a PC via USB. We've started looking into automatic testing, but so far I'm unable to find a tool that can record/replay generic USB  input.

Does anyone know of such a tool?
(And - it would be best if it's somehow scriptable - testing would have to alternate between GUI interaction *and* custom hardware manipulation)

Comment: As an aside, you would be well off using dependency injection and an isolation (mocking) framework to test the remainder of your application. Definitely integration-test the USB classes, but do so separately from testing the rest of your classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware solution,

Do you want to generate USB traffic. It's long since I used it, but the CATC protocol analyzer can also generate traffic. 
http://www.lecroy.com/tm/products/ProtocolAnalyzers/usbtt.asp?menuid=67
And off course, you can write scripts to generate these traffic ...

Software solution,

Write your own application to send packets to the USB bus driver, and also check the usbview (shipped with Windows DDK) source code. You can send data directly to any USB pipe. This is less expensive, but a bit difficult than the hardware solution ...

HTH

Answer (score 4):

### Mocking usb devices using umockdev

Umockdev is a linux based application which record the behaviour as well as properties of hardware and run the software independent of actual hardware it is running on. Hardware devices can be simulated in virtual environments
without disturbing the whole system.It currently supports sysfs, uevents, basic support for /dev devices, and recording/mocking usbdevfs ioctls (for PtP/MTP devices). It helps for creating integration test for hardware related libraries.

[source code and examples](https://github.com/martinpitt/umockdev)

[umockdev home page](https://launchpad.net/umockdev)

Comment: can it be used on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of test tools on the usb.org [tools page](http://www.usb.org/developers/tools/), not sure if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but seems these are all USB protocol-conformance testing tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a simple program using [Usblib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx). Its easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if any USB analyzers have option for  replay they have for sure option for record. Right now I can think of only LeCroy but there are others companies that make USB analyzers. But they cost similar, LeCroy would be rather top price. Here you should get fair comparison of USB analyzers and their price. www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=533 (have to register to see article)

Comment: Chris - can you give an example USB analyzer?