# How do I build a virtual USB simulator?

Tags: usb, virtual

We are looking for a virtual USB link simulator; this program or service should 
link a virtual [COM port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29) to an application which accepts only USB as data link.

The [virtual COM port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector#Virtual_Serial_Port) is [VSPE](http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html) from [Eterlogic](http://www.eterlogic.com/).

The purpose is to make a serial data link between this virtual port and an application that expects data from a USB stick. Instead of the stick (recognized as HID) the program should get serial data from the virtual COM port ([RS-232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232)) presented as a virtual USB connection.

Comment: You also seem to need a keyboard with a working Caps-Lock key ;)

Comment: mocking usb device for linux platform http://stackoverflow.com/a/43917529/6180077

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "Accepts only USB as data link" ?

HID is a standard Device Class.
It contains some standardized "Usage tables" (e.g. Mouse, Keyboard, Monitor control).

Most Operating Systems know how to handle HID and a number of Usage table. Connecting such a device will result with the OS exporting an appropriate device (Keyboard).

Since you can register with HID in user-space in Windows (for a new Class Driver implementation, one needs to create a full driver). Many manufacturers are "riding" HID's back to create custom protocols on top of it.

1. Does your application interact with a HID device that exports one of the standard usage tables ? (http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/)
2. Does your application register on top of HID and parse the reports itself ?
3. Does your application connect to 3d party driver already installed on your OS ?

   - Not enough space to post this in comments

Comment: Let me explain the problem we try to solve:
We designed a special communication tool that can be used on a wheelchair by paraplegic (paralysed) persons.
In order to control the environment (lights, heating etc..) we use Z-wave. Thinkessentials is an application that allows control via pc of Z-w

Comment: We designed a special communication tool for use on a wheelchair To control lights etc. we use Z-wave. We have app for control of these devices via pc.
Unfortunately, app expects a USB stick. Our design does not allow stick. Instead we use serial interface that comes into the pc via Bluetooth, hence the virtual com.
We know app does not need third-party drivers, it uses HID to create virtual comport inside app. 
Is a program possible that simulates USB and links the app to BT virtual com?
Pls bear in mind that i am not a programmer. We are looking for someone who could do this for us.

Jacob

Comment: It appears that you have three choices:
1. Modify the app
2. Fool the app to register against a custom layer instead of the existing Windows HID driver
3. Create a HID minidriver to expose your serial bus as another HID bus. (Will require users to install a driver to use your system)

Not sure if (2) is doable. (3) Will require a developer with experience in windows driver development.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks Murkin. Modifying app is too complex as his author says.
The best option i guess is 3, where we intend a universal solution being a USB driver that simulates the PnP process (since there is no hardware to be connected) and links the data from the virtual comport to the app. If you should happen to know a developer who could do this, please let us know.
Thanks again,
Jacob