# Virtual USB device

Tags: windows, usb, device-driver

I have been googling for a virtual USB stub.

The idea is to make a driver that you can feed with the dataflow that normally comes from the USB controller chip.

From windows it should work transparent, so it shows the "Installing New Hardware" bubble and ect., when a virtual device is connected.

I know about the USB/IP open source project, is there any other projects libraries?

Comment: mocking usb device for linux platform http://stackoverflow.com/a/43917529/6180077