# Is it possible to Mock an FTDI USB device?

Tags: c#, .net, usb, driver, ftdi

I need to write an FTDI application in C# to interact with a specialised piece of hardware located at another site.

When using the `FTD2XX_NET.dll`wrapper for the C# application, I receive:

> Failed to load FTD2XX.DLL. Are the FTDI drivers installed?

when calling `FTDI myFtdiDevice = new FTDI();`

As I've already used the .exe for installing the FTDI drivers, I'm *assuming* that this is a problem of not finding any devices with the driver installed.

My question pertains to whether or not I can mock such a device for the purposes of easier programming and some but limited testing.

Thanks.

Comment: usb mocking application http://stackoverflow.com/a/43917529/6180077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to plug in an FTDI device at least once to have the driver files to be copied over to the system32 folder and the necessary entries for the device in the registry.

Regards,
Savyasaachi Keshava Murthy
Applications Engineer
FTDi Chip, USA