# Creating virtual USB device in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, kernel, iokit, kernel-extension

I tried to add virtual usb device with driver in Mac OS programmatically.
IOKit documentations says: Traditionally, drivers of virtual devices match on IOResources because virtual devices do not publish nubs of their own. Another example of such a driver is the HelloIOKit KEXT (described in “Creating a Device Driver with Xcode”) which matches on IOResources because it does not control any hardware.

But I don't found way to add virtual device in system. How can I do that?

Comment: umockdev is a usb mocking application for linux platform : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43917529/6180077

Comment: Did you ever manage to do what you wanted to? And perhaps published it somewhere? Anyway, this project might provide you with a starting point: https://github.com/unbit/foohid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What are you actually trying to do?

If you want to create a virtual USB device, you will also have to create a virtual USB controller (`IOUSBController`/`IOUSBControllerV2`/`IOUSBControllerV3` subclass) to which the virtual USB device would be attached. The controller itself would match on `IOResources` and would have to emulate the functionality of a real USB controller. The virtual controller would pretend to detect the virtual USB device on its "bus", and offer the device/interface nubs up for real USB device drivers to match against. This is probably a lot of work - are you sure your virtual device must be a USB one?

Comment: Thank you for your message. I'm doing it for educational purposes. Can you please provide any samples of virtual USB controller?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen any code like this myself - I know a few people have mentioned doing this kind of thing in the past on StackOverflow. I have no idea if they've ever published that code. It's not impossible to do yourself from scratch, it'll probably just take quite a bit of code.

Comment: I also would be interested to see some example code. Perhaps will publish some examples if I'll make any.

Comment: @MariusKarnauskas note that my answer is from 2013. A lot has changed in macOS since then. IOUSBFamily is obsolete, and IOUSBHostFamily kexts only work in exceptional circumstances when using certain APIs which don’t have DriverKit equivalents. I am unaware of any successful virtual usb implementations on recent macOS versions.

Comment: Gotcha. Haven't realised this was so old post. Yes, there have been some changes around 3rd party kext support. I had silly idea to (somehow) expose/access T2 as a U2F virtual device. I have no idea if it's really possible or there's better way to do it.