# How to emulate a gamepad on Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, gamepad, emulation

I would like to create a program that can emulate a gamepad being connected to the computer and pressing buttons/using the joystick on that virtual gamepad to control other games on OS X. However, I cannot find anywhere on how to emulate the gamepad/gamepad button presses.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064648/creating-virtual-usb-device-in-mac-os-x

Comment: This project uses c++, worth having a look: https://github.com/unbit/foohid

Answer (score 2):

Wjoy — an Nintendo Wiimote to gamepad event mapper — seem to know how to emulate a gamepad in OS X.

https://github.com/alxn1/wjoy

They do include «virtual HID interface driver (can be used for **creating virtual mouses, keyboars, joysticks**)».

And it's open source.